# Angular Table Content Not Displaying Properl API

Tags: html, angular, angularjs, typescript, angular-material

The API Returns an array of objects so that i could extract it and loop it through and make ROWS out of it . but the problem is it displays only one element in the row and makes 2 entries of Rows . but When i click on the choose files options (there is a column in which we can choose files) and give a file path . the data of the other row displays also there is a file extension column which is a drop down . the data from this drop down also comes from an API .this functionality works when i add a path to the file . i think there is some rendering issue . This is my HTML code for the table

```
<div class="card" >
  <hr>
  <div class="card-header">
    <h2>Bank Statements of {{this.selectedOptionProduct}}</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="loading-spinner" *ngIf="productSelectedForLoading && loading">
      <div class="spinner"></div>
    </div>
    <table class="table" >
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Product Name</th>
          <th>File Uploads</th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th> File extenstion </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        
        <tr *ngFor="let row of tableData " >
          <td>{{ row.file_type_id }}</td>
          <td>
            <input type="file"  #fileInput [value]="row.file_type_id" (change)="onFileSelected($event, row)">
            <button (click)="uploadFile(row)">Upload</button>
            <button (click)="resetFileInput(fileInput)">Reset</button>
          </td>
          <td>{{ row.status }}</td>
          <td>
            <select (change)="onOptionSelectedExtention($event.target)" >
              <option>Select one </option>
              <option *ngFor="let extention of row.file_extensions" mat-menu-item [value]="extention" >{{extention}}</option>
              
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
     
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

This is my component.ts file for those functions

```
tableData: any[] = [ 
];

selectedExtention : String

loading: boolean = true;


onOptionSelectedExtention(selectedOption : any){
    this.selectedExtention=selectedOption.value
    console.log(this.selectedExtention)
}

async getTableData(selectedProduct: any) {
    try {
    const url = `API?product_id=${selectedProduct}`;
    const response = await axios.get(url);
    const data = response.data;

    this.tableData = data;
    this.loading = false;
    console.log(this.tableData);

    // Flatten the tableData array
    this.flattenedTableData = this.tableData.reduce((accumulator, row) => {
        return accumulator.concat(row.items);
    }, []);
    console.log(this.flattenedTableData);

    // Use the variable as needed
    console.log(data);
    } catch (error) {
    // Handle any errors
    console.error('Error:', error);
    }
}

resetFileInput(fileInput: HTMLInputElement) {
    fileInput.value = ''; // Reset the value of the file input field
}

onFileSelected(event: any, row: any) {
    row.selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
    console.log(row.selectedFile['name'])
}

uploadFile(row: any) {
    const file = row.selectedFile;
    console.log(file);
    
    if (file) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);

    // Make an HTTP request to upload the file
    this.http.post('your-upload-api-url', formData)
        .subscribe(
        response => {
            // Handle success response, e.g., update status
            row.status = 'Uploaded';
        },
        error => {
            // Handle error response, e.g., display an error message
            console.log("hello")
        }
        );
    }
}
```

And this only happens when i have two objects in that array from the API . how to fix it . here are some of the SS for visual representation. This picture is when i don't hit choose the file option as you could see this does not render the second row items neither the file extension  [image]

edit :

This is after hitting choose files and it re rendered [image]

The API response for the table
[image]

The updated image when i choose the file path
[image]

Comment: The two screenshots look exactly the same? What is the use of this.flattenedTableData? Should you not have your *ngFor on the flattendedTableData object rather than the tableDataObject? Please provide the data returned by the API.

Comment: I have updated the changes and added the API responses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using property binding rather than just assigning a a string value to your input. Therefor, the first row renders correctly, but when the second row is rendered, there is a conflict as the property is already bound to the first row's input. This results in the following DOM exception:

"ERROR DOMException: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string."

You can resolve this by simply removing brackets on your [value] property. This will assign a string value rather that binding the property.

Ex.

```
         <td>
            <input type="file"  #fileInput value="row.file_type_id" (change)="onFileSelected($event, row)">
            <button (click)="uploadFile(row)">Upload</button>
            <button (click)="resetFileInput(fileInput)">Reset</button>
          </td>
```